# Create a summary result with one query

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I have a table with the following format.

```
mysql> describe unit_characteristics;
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uut_id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| uut_sn               | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| characteristic_name  | varchar(80)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| characteristic_value | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| creation_time        | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_modified_time   | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

each uut_sn has multiple characteristic_name/value pairs.  I want to use MySQL to generate a table

```
+----------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| uut_sn | char_name_1 | char_name_2 | char_name_3 | char_name_4 | ...          |
+----------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 00000  | char_val_1  | char_val_2  | char_val_3  | char_val_4  | ...          | 
| 00001  | char_val_1  | char_val_2  | char_val_3  | char_val_4  | ...          |
| 00002  | char_val_1  | char_val_2  | char_val_3  | char_val_4  | ...          |
| .....  | char_val_1  | char_val_2  | char_val_3  | char_val_4  | ...          |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+--------------+
```

Is this possible with just one query?

Thanks,
-peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard pivot query:

```
  SELECT uc.uut_sn,
         MAX(CASE 
               WHEN uc.characteristic_name = 'char_name_1' THEN uc.characteristic_value 
               ELSE NULL 
             END) AS char_name_1,
         MAX(CASE 
               WHEN uc.characteristic_name = 'char_name_2' THEN uc.characteristic_value 
               ELSE NULL 
             END) AS char_name_2,
         MAX(CASE 
               WHEN uc.characteristic_name = 'char_name_3' THEN uc.characteristic_value 
               ELSE NULL 
             END) AS char_name_3,
    FROM unit_characteristics uc
GROUP BY uc.uut_sn
```

To make it dynamic, you need to use [MySQL's dynamic SQL syntax called Prepared Statements](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html).  It requires two queries - the first gets a list of the `characteristic_name` values, so you can concatenate the appropriate string into the CASE expressions like you see in my example as the ultimate query.

Comment: +1 Nitpick: `null` is the default when no `when` matches, so you could omit the `else null`

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Both of the solutions and explanation are great.  I had to select @OMG Ponies answer better I was not familiar with table pivot.

@Bill, I'm not familiar with EAV antipattern, so I googled the terms and you seem to have many slides regarding the subject, is there a version with an audio?  It looks like you are against EAV, but what happens when there are many name/value pairs?  Does translating them into columns make sense if there are over 200 names/value pair?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the EAV antipattern.  There's no way to automatically generate the pivot table you describe, without hardcoding the characteristics you want to include.  As @OMG Ponies mentions, you need to use dynamic SQL to general the query in a custom fashion for the set of characteristics you want to include in the result.

Instead, I recommend you fetch the characteristics one per row, as they are stored in the database, and if you want an application object to represent a single UUT with all its characteristics, you write code to loop over the rows as you fetch them in your application, collecting them into objects.

For example in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT uut_sn, characteristic_name, characteristic_value 
        FROM unit_characteristics";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);

$objects = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  if (!isset($objects[ $row["uut_sn"] ])) {
      $object[ $row["uut_sn"] ] = new Uut();
  }
  $objects[ $row["uut_sn"] ]->$row["characteristic_name"] 
                            = $row["characterstic_value"];
}
```

This has a few advantages over the solution of hardcoding characteristic names in your query:

- This solution takes only one SQL query instead of two.
- No complex code is needed to build your dynamic SQL query.
- If you forget one of the characteristics, this solution automatically finds it anyway.
- GROUP BY in MySQL is often slow, and this avoids the GROUP BY.